# Using bottom with position relative?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I am trying to get a series of `<a>` tags appear at the base of their parent `<li>`.

The problem is two fold. If I use `position: relative`, `bottom: 0;` has no effect. If I use `position: absolute`, the `<li>`'s have overlapping widths.

I can fix the first problem by using the `top` style, but this is not ideal as the text size is unknown, and the top element measure from the top of both elements (so the base of the element would not hit the base unless I knew the font size).

I can fix the second with defined widths, but this will add unwanted white space on elements with shorter titles.

[Here is a JSFiddle of the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/K8bJQ/)

Comment: You don't want to add a margin/padding-top to your li/a elements?

Comment: Same problem with varying font sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this bit of CSS:

```
#main-menu li a{
    display: table-cell; 
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 111px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8bJQ/13/) of the working style

Comment: As far as my research can see, the only browser compatibility issue with this is that needs to be applied on and inline element for IE7, which in this instance is fine. Anyone know of any reason this would fail?

Answer (score 0):

Add a line-height value to your "#main-menu li a" style and position accordingly, 200px should work.

Comment: This is imperfect, as it also depends on font-size.